# Exclude Images from Lightbox Gallery in Typo3

Tags: image, lightbox, typo3, typoscript

I have a Typo3 Project, in which I realized a Image-Gallery with Lightbox and the following TypoScript code:

```
tt_content.image.20.1.imageLinkWrap >
tt_content.image.20.1.imageLinkWrap = 1

tt_content.image.20.1.imageLinkWrap {
  enable = 1
  JSwindow = 0
  directImageLink = 1
  linkParams.ATagParams.dataWrap = class="lightbox" rel="lightbox{field:uid}"
}
```

Now I have the problem, that other pictures on the page, which are not part of the content (eg. the logo on the top), get also the "lightbox"-class and the -rel attribute.
How can I exclude all images which are not part of the Gallery?

thx

Answer (score 0):

Which version of TYPO3 are you using? Did you know that image records have a checkbox which says "Enlarge on click"? When checked, an anchor tag with a class and a rel attribute is rendered around the image. You can set both in the constants editor of the root TypoScript template in CONTENT. Initially it is set to the values you have chosen in your TypoScript:

```
class="lightbox" rel="lightbox{field:uid}
```